# Why can't I explicitly cast an int to a string?

Tags: c#, casting

If I try to do this it doesn't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 5000;
    Console.WriteLine((string)a);
}
```

But somehow this works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 5000;
    Console.WriteLine(a + "");
}
```

Why is that? Is it because the first is trying to change the base type and the second just appends the value to the string?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`int` cannot be cast to `string` (1), but there is an operator `+` that accepts `int` as left-hand argument and `string` as right-hand argument (2). This operator converts the `int` to `string` and concatenates the two `string`s.

A better approach would probably be to just use `Console.WriteLine(a);` which would call `a.ToString()` for you.

Comment: Upvote for identifying it's the operator that does the conversion.

Comment: aka, you're misinterpreting the cast operator, which shouldn't call the toString method.

Comment: I can't find such an operator defined on either `String` or `Int32`... Where is it defined?

Comment: @Damien I suspect it's defined in the C# compiler. Just like you won't find lifted operators when looking at the `Nullable<T>` type.

Comment: In this case call is made to System.String.Concat, not operator.

Comment: Section "7.8.4 Addition operator" in Microsoft's C# language specification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) shows the definition.

Comment: @tinman you beat me to it: "If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string is substituted."

Answer (score 7):

So you are getting a compile time error right? The problem is is that int does not explicitly cast to string.

So

```
(string)a
```

is not valid code but

```
a + ""
```

mean that the code will work because it basically get translated to

```
a.ToString() + ""
```

So the int gets converted into a string value

Comment: It's not possible to write an overloaded conversion operator from int to string. What type would you write the operator on? (We considered adding "extension conversion operators" to C# 4 but never got past the design stage.)

Comment: @Eric, of course you are right (surprisingly), I had thought I would be able to do like with extension methods. Never needed to do it before, and never tried until now. Just something I assumed would be possible. Even if you had added it I don't think I would ever use. It could be misleading as it would not be obvious that it was using an extension and it may confuse other coders when reading some code

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 5000;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

that implicitly calls `a.ToString()`

Comment: whatever it uses... it works. Nowhere in the question did it say anything about operator+. Question asked why it didn't work... this answer, and others, points out why.

Answer (score 1):

> To cast a int in a string you must use int32.parse(string )

That's not right, the parse method of Int32 returns an integer, which is parsed from a string.

To get the string representation of another datatype just use .ToString() from Object Class.
Or you use System.Convert.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because as you have assigned an purely `integer` value in to a you can not convert it into `string` by an implicit conversion, but which will work as follows

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 5000;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

which is equal to `Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());`